# How To Pass Values Into Database using ArrayList Object using OOP concept

Tags: java, oop, jdbc, arraylist

I'm try to pass values into database, I'm trying to get Input by User and Pass it to Database via another class called Custmer.class.And i have create getter/Setters in Other class. Can someone please help me to do this.

Here's my Custmr.class code

```
public class Custmer {

   ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(); 
   public void Custmer(ArrayList arrlist){
      this.arrlist= arrlist;
   }

    //return msg;
    Connection con;
    public void passingMsg(ArrayList<Inquiries> arrlist){
        try {
            System.out.println("Method "+arrlist);
            String sq = "INSERT INTO Inquiries (name,mail,tp,msg)VALUES(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement(sq);

            for(int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++){
                //don't know how to do here's onward 
            }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
         }
    }
}
```

and this is how i got user input(I want to Use OOP concept)

```
 String name = txtName.getText();
        String mail = txtEmail.getText();
        String tp = txtTp.getText();
        String msg = txtMsg.getText();

        ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrlist.add(name);
        arrlist.add(mail);
        arrlist.add(tp);
        arrlist.add(msg);

        Custmer c =new Custmer();
        c.passingMsg(arrlist);
```

And I have wrote all the getter and setters in Inquiries Class

Can some one please help me to complete

Comment: if you wrote the code so far by yourself, i am sure you can manage to write the rest yourself too. just try, and if it fails, come back here with the error or problem. as it is , this is not a problem, but a request for work. side remark: don't use something like `ArrayList arrlist`. better describe what is in there, then describe the type, because the type already describes itsself. also, you nearly always want to use `List<String> fooBar = new ArrayList<>();` because later on you do not care which list it is, and you do not want to duplicate the `String` part.

Comment: I'd use a `Map` instead of a `ArrayList` or simply pass the parameters directly or via some kind of POJO

Comment: What's the database table column names?  What does the `Inquiries` class look like?

Comment: table names are "name,mail,tp,msg".that is Inquiries Class code is where i made all da getters and setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a class Inquiry with attributes you need and provide getter and setter methods.

```
class Inquiry{
    String name;
    String mail;
    String tp;
    String message;

    public Inquiry(String name,String mail,String tp,String message){
        this.name = name;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.tp = tp;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }
    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    public String getTp() {
        return tp;
    }
    public void setTp(String tp) {
        this.tp = tp;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

2. Change String to Inquiry in below line

   ```
   ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```
3. While adding Inquiry to `ArrayList`, add like this

   ```
   arrlist.add(new Inquiry(name,mail,tp,message));
   ```
4. Provide values of `Inquiry` object into insert statement values by using getter methods of each value.